# Tkinter's Text with wrap=none cannot be scrolled horizontally for more than a width of a visible lines

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, tcl, horizontal-scrolling

I've been tinkering around with [PAGE](http://page.sourceforge.net/)'s implementation of scrolled widgets when i noticed that horizontal scrollbar of the ScrolledText widget will disappear if long lines are not visible. Turns out this has nothing to do with horizontal scrollbar and is [original Tk behavior](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm):

> *pathName* **xview**
>
> Returns a list containing two elements. Each element is a real fraction between 0 and 1; together they describe the portion of the document's horizontal span that is visible in the window. For example, if the first element is .2 and the second element is .6, 20% of the text is off-screen to the left, the middle 40% is visible in the window, and 40% of the text is off-screen to the right. **The fractions refer only to the lines that are actually visible in the window: if the lines in the window are all very short, so that they are entirely visible, the returned fractions will be 0 and 1, even if there are other lines in the text that are much wider than the window.**

With auto-hiding scrollbars, scrolling vertically makes horizontal scrollbar constantly shrink, widen and sometimes disappear (later affects vertical scrollbar).

How can i circumvent this?

Relevant source (mostly generated by PAGE, with some additions from me for another scrolled widget):

```
class AutoScroll(object):
    """Configure the scrollbars for a widget."""

    def __init__(self, master, cbl=None):
        try:
            vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical', command=self.yview)
        except:
            pass
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='horizontal', command=self.xview)

        try:
            self.configure(yscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(vsb, cbl))
        except:
            pass
        self.configure(xscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(hsb, cbl))

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        try:
            vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
        except:
            pass
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Copy geometry methods of master (taken from ScrolledText.py)

        methods = (
            Pack.__dict__.keys() |
            Grid.__dict__.keys() |
            Place.__dict__.keys()
        )

        for meth in methods:
            if (meth[0] != "_" and meth not in ("config", "configure") and
                    meth not in type(self).__bases__[0].__dict__):
                setattr(self, meth, getattr(master, meth))

    def clscroll(self, cbl):
        # Checklist elements scroll
        root.update()
        for i, w in enumerate(cbl[1]):
            bb = ttk.Treeview.bbox(self, i, "#0")
            if bb == "":
                w.place_forget()
            else:
                x, y, _, _ = bb
                w.place(x=x+(tvhh-2)/2, y=y+tvrh/2, anchor='center')
                cbl[0].place(x=x+(tvhh-2)/2, anchor='center')
        root.update()

    # @staticmethod
    def _autoscroll(self, sbar, cbl):
        """Hide and show scrollbar as needed."""
        def wrapped(first, last):
            if cbl:
                self.clscroll(cbl)
            first, last = float(first), float(last)
            if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
                sbar.grid_remove()
            else:
                sbar.grid()
            sbar.set(first, last)
        return wrapped

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.master)

def _create_container(func):
    """Creates a ttk Frame with a given master, and use this new frame to
    place the scrollbars and the widget."""
    def wrapped(cls, master, **kw):
        container = ttk.Frame(master)
        return func(cls, container, **kw)
    return wrapped

class ScrolledText(AutoScroll, Text):
    """A standard Tkinter Text widget with scrollbars that will
    automatically show/hide as needed."""
    @_create_container
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Text.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        AutoScroll.__init__(self, master)
```

---

Edit by TheLizzard

Shorter mre:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MyScrollbar(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, bg="red", height=10, width=1,
                         highlightthickness=0)

    def set(self, low, high):
        if (low == "0.0") and (high == "1.0"):
            self.pack_forget()
        elif (low != "0.0") or (high != "1.0"):
            self.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    scrollbar = MyScrollbar(root)
    scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    text = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=10, wrap="none",
                   xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    text.insert("end", "aa"+"\n"*12+"a"*31)
    text.pack(side="top", fill="both")

    # Scroll up/down to see the scrollbar (in red) disappear and reappear
```

Comment: Couldn't come up with anything other then re-implementing whole widget (which i'm totally not in the mood to do). Filed a RFE ([link](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/71fccf432be64bc8e41d02620ccc701dc6f6768e)).

Comment: Any updates on this? I am having this same problem 7 years later. One possible approach would be to implement something like the `xview` by using maximum from `count` `ypixels` `"{line}.0"` `"{line}.end"` to get the width of the longest line.

Comment: We should have better metrics for the display lines than we used to; computing them is the very expensive part of the layout algorithm. It might be possible to alter the behaviour. (The chance of it breaking existing code is tiny.) I know that we have better vertical metrics; similar fixing was done in that direction.